# What are some affordable API options for an Electronic Components Database?

Tags: web-development, api, web, information-management

I am trying to build a site that sells electronic components (transistors, microprocessors, etc.) and I need to list specifications for the products. *See a full list of required features below.*

[Silicon Expert](https://www.siliconexpert.com/products/web-services) provides an API that accomplishes this, but it is out of our price range. We have a budget for this service of $300/month.

**Full list of required features**

- A large database of electronic components (transistors, microprocessors, etc.)
- API available to access data
- Provides product specifications (Operating temperatures, Voltages, etc.)
- Provides datasheets
- Provides product images
- $300/month or less

Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: My search for online APIs starts and usually ends at https://www.programmableweb.com  Only one I found though is https://www.programmableweb.com/api/arrow-electronics